# Extended enum class

Tags: c++, enums, c++11, static-members, enum-class

I had enum class, say

```
enum class Enum{
   var1, var2;
}
```

Now I want to add some member which depends on parameter i.e `var3(int)`. OK, It's not for enum, so I want to change it by regular class, but my goal is to leave old code(`Enum::var1` as value of type `Enum`) possible to compile.

I tried to do it this way(let's temporary forgot about `var3`, it'll be static function):

```
class Enum{
    public:
        const static Enum var1 = Enum(1);
        const static Enum var2 = Enum(2);
    private:
        Enum(int v):v(v){
        }
    int v;
    //operator == using v
};
```

But it doesn't compile because Enum has incomplete type.
I can't declare it after class because it's in header so it'll not work with multiple cpp's. Besides, it's not great idea to have public constructor here.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The biggest problem with this will be that you couldn't use `Enum::var1` where a constant expression is required.

Comment: @Xeo1: will constexpr fix it? BTW, no need to use as constexpr(for now, maybe)

Comment: No, since a class type can't be used as a, say, non-type template parameter.

Comment: @Xeo: anyway, if I want add something that depends on parameter, I'll never have this advantage:), But thanks for useful comment.

Comment: You wanted that everyone can use `Enum::var1` just the same as before. However, if `var1` is of type `Enum` now, and `Enum` is a class-type, and you used `Enum::var1` in a constant expression before, the code will not compile anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

For the static variable problem: declare your static variables in the class declaration:

```
class Enum
{
    public:
        static const Enum var1;
        static const Enum var2;
        Enum(int v):v(v)
        {
        }
    private:
        int v;
        //operator == using v
};
```

Then, create a source file for this class, `Enum.cpp`, containing:

```
#include "Enum.h"
const Enum Enum::var1 = Enum(1);
const Enum Enum::var2 = Enum(2);
```

**Solution 2:**

If you want it to be header-only, you can use static variables instead of class variables:

```
class Enum
{
    public:
        Enum(int v):v(v)
        {
        }
    private:
        int v;
};

namespace Enumeration // It is not possible to name it 'Enum'
{
    // static => local to translation unit. No linking conflict
    static const Enum var1 = Enum(1);
    static const Enum var2 = Enum(2);
}
```

You can see [a live example here](http://ideone.com/nnxjQo). The only drawback is that you cannot use the name of the class for the namespace.

Comment: It's cool, but I want to void it because I need to provide ONLY header to end-user

Comment: Won't be able to use them where a constant expression is required.

Comment: BTW doesn't compile with private ctor. Fixed it in your code.

Comment: @RiaD, you can write initialization `var1` and `var2` in Enum.h, after class declaration.

Comment: @Ruu and user will get compile error with two cpp's that include it.

Comment: @RiaD, you can not initialize variables `static const <type>` where type is not `int`. `constexpr`

Comment: @Riad Thanks for the fix. Now that I know you want a header-only solution, I've added a solution. See my edit.

Comment: I thought about second solution. I think it's not so great but the best of possible, so I'm going to use it

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class like this:

```
class Enum
{
public
    enum NestedEnum : int
    {
        var1, var2
    };

    static NestedEnum var3;

    Enum(NestedEnum value) : value(value) { }

    operator NestedEnum() const { return value; }
private:
    NestedEnum value;
};
```

And anywhere else you can declare:

```
Enum::var3 = (Enum::NestedEnum)someIntegerVariable;
```